# How can I run Linter only on changed files?

Tags: git, github-actions, lint

I have a project with many js files and I don't wanna run the validation for all files in the CI, only the edited ones. There's a simple command to do that? or should I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using one of the existing actions in the Marketplace.

https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files

And the pass the output of this to your linter.

You can also play with `git log` to get those files, but to cover all cases in PRs, branches etc... it's getting really complicated so it doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel imho.